# System Info in Batch?

Tags: html, batch-file, cmd, html-table, operating-system

Is there any way in batch that I can output the following information to a HTML file with a table, or if that's not possible a text document?

- OS
- Computer Name (Network)
- Amount of RAM
- CPU Speed
- Currently Logged on User
- Any Suggestions?

If some of these aren't possible, that's fine, but I know most are, because my school has a batch file like this, for the Help Desk, but they converted it into an exe, so I can't view the code. (there's outputs to a nice looking HTML table. If anyone could help, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below code will give you full info of system(remove that quotes):

```
    : FULL SYSTEM INFO    
    : START CMD    

    : Set the dialog title    
    title FULL SYSTEM INFO    

    @echo off    

    : Display nothing but add whitespace    
     echo.

    : Displaying text    
    echo Exporting System Info...

    : Using the SYSTEMINFO command and export it directly into a text file    
    SYSTEMINFO>INFO.txt

    : Display nothing but add whitespace    
    echo.

    : Displaying text    
    echo INFO.txt Exported!

    : Open the newly exported file in notepad    
    notepad.exe INFO.txt    

    : Wait on user    
    pause    

    : STOP CMD
```

Comment: copy,paste code in batch file and run without any change.

Answer (score 2):

You could try this one line code it should tell you every thing you need:

```
systeminfo | findstr /B /C:"OS Name" /C:"OS Version" /C:"OS Manufacturer" /C:"OS Configuration" /C:"OS Build Type" /C:"Original Install Date" /C:"System Boot Time" /C:"System Manufacturer" /C:"System Model" /C:"System Type" /C:"Processor(s)" /C:"BIOS Version" /C:"Windows Directory" /C:"System Directory" /C:"Boot Device" /C:"System Locale" /C:"Input Locale" /C:"Total Physical Memory" /C:"Available Physical Memory" /C:"Virtual Memory: Max Size" /C:"Virtual Memory: Available" /C:"Virtual Memory: In Use" /C:"Domain" /C:"Network Card(s)"
```

To see the output you will also need a pause and for it to be more tidy you will need a @echo off so it would be like this:

```
@echo off
systeminfo | findstr /B /C:"OS Name" /C:"OS Version" /C:"OS Manufacturer" /C:"OS Configuration" /C:"OS Build Type" /C:"Original Install Date" /C:"System Boot Time" /C:"System Manufacturer" /C:"System Model" /C:"System Type" /C:"Processor(s)" /C:"BIOS Version" /C:"Windows Directory" /C:"System Directory" /C:"Boot Device" /C:"System Locale" /C:"Input Locale" /C:"Total Physical Memory" /C:"Available Physical Memory" /C:"Virtual Memory: Max Size" /C:"Virtual Memory: Available" /C:"Virtual Memory: In Use" /C:"Domain" /C:"Network Card(s)"
pause
```